# Perl function call confused me

Tags: perl, function-call

A perl function call confused me， could anyone help me？

`catFiles` called like this:

```
catFiles( \@LINKFILES => "$output_prefix.links" );
```

`catFiles` function define：

```
sub catFiles {

    unlink("$_[1]") if(exists $_[1]);
    system qq( cat "$_" >> "$_[1]" ) for @{$_[0]};
}
```

I don't know why there are `=>` there which I think it should be a `,`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`=>` is (almost) equivalent to `,` in Perl. (See [the "official" documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) for the differences.)

Usually it's used when defining a hash to indicate the relationship between key and value:

```
my %hash = (
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
);
```

We could write it as `my %hash = ('a', 1, 'b', 2);` with no change in behavior but that doesn't look as nice. You could even do `my $hash = ('a', 1 => 'b', 2);` but that's just confusing.

Similarly, in your case you could write the code as

```
catFiles(\@LINKFILES, "$output_prefix.links");
```

and it would do the same thing as the `=>` version.

Here it's getting used as syntactic sugar, I guess to indicate that the contents of `@LINKFILES` will get concatenated into `"$output_prefix.links"`.